# Can't delete a record in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having trouble in deleting a record that has file in it. Below is the code.

delete file method :

```
private function deletePDF(Journal $journal) {
        $exist = Storage::disk('file')->exists($journal->file);

        if (isset($journal->file) && $exist) {
            $delete = Storage::disk('file')->delete($journal->file);
            if ($delete) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Destroy method :

```
public function destroy(Journal $journal, EditionRequest $request) {
    $this->deletePDF($journal);
    $journal->delete();

    return redirect()->route('edition', ['id' => $request->id]);
}
```

The result game me nothing, it's just return to the page where the record belongs and does not deleting the record. I used the same code for another project with the same laravel version and it's working, but for some reasons it doesn't work here and I'm a lil bit confused.

Update :

EditionRequest :

```
public function rules() {
        // Cek apakah CREATE atau UPDATE
        $id = $this->get('id');
        if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
            $volume_rules = 'required|integer|unique_with:edition,number,' . $id;
            $number_rules = 'required|integer';
        } else {
            $volume_rules = 'required|integer|unique_with:edition,number';
            $number_rules = 'required|integer';
        }
        return [
            'volume' => $volume_rules,
            'number' => $number_rules,
            'cover' => 'sometimes|image|max:15000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it returns to the same page as before, you probably have a validation error in your request!

You can check the errors easily by adding the following snippet to your view:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

With this you should be able to see what's going wrong. Let me know if it worked :)

**edit**

```
public function rules() {
        // Cek apakah CREATE atau UPDATE
        $id = $this->get('id');
        if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
            $volume_rules = 'required|integer|unique_with:edition,number,' . $id;
            $number_rules = 'required|integer';
        }  

        else if($this->method() == 'DELETE'){
             //your delete validation rules rules
             $volume_rules = ''
             $number_rules= '';              
        } 

        else {
            $volume_rules = 'required|integer|unique_with:edition,number';
            $number_rules = 'required|integer';
        }
        return [
            'volume' => $volume_rules,
            'number' => $number_rules,
            'cover' => 'sometimes|image|max:15000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png',
        ];
    }
```

You might even want to not use the request youre using now, which would give you this:

```
public function destroy(Journal $journal, Request $request)
```

Comment: you mean adding the snippet to the view that shows the record ? if so then the snippet gave me this error Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::has(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\2mark\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag.php on line 82 and defined (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\2mark\resources\views\edition\show.blade.php)

Comment: @AriandoMiller did an update, try that, and indeed add it to the page view that pops up when it redirects back

Comment: works! it gave me this result 
    The volume field is required.
    The number field is required.
I'm updating my question now to show you the request

Comment: @AriandoMiller Accept as answer and upvote if it worked would be awesome :)

Comment: Of course I will :), but it does not fix the problem yet, it shows me that the problem is seems to be in my request and I have no idea what I did wrong

Comment: Tried both of it and gave me this error : InvalidArgumentException in FilesystemManager.php line 121: Driver [] is not supported.